Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'
This happened just after i added photo manager package.
here's the complete error i'm getting
Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.
Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

I tried flutter clean & flutter pub get, still didn't work.
here are the versions i'm using:
Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3
Flutter 3.24.5 • channel stable
